# Why SQL Select Statement incorrect syntax?

Tags: sql

New to SQL we were taught syntax informally and don't know what i'm missing.

Database cannot be changed

```
Select Sum('Unit Price') as TotalPrice, Count('Order ID') as NumOfDiffProds, 
Avg(Quantity) as AvgQuantity, Avg(Discount) as AvgDiscount
From [Order Details]
Where [Order ID] = 1
```

I get this error:

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Comment: what is your error - you are missing your tablename

Comment: "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect"

Comment: Also please refrain from vandalizing your own question. The column name with whitespaces should be wrapped in brackets.

Comment: Column names with spaces need to be enclosed in double quotes in SQL. And square brackets are invalid in standard SQL.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: no - they should be enclosed in double quotes  - at least in "SQL" (as in "standard SQL"). Square brackets are invalid in (standard) "SQL"

Answer (score 0):

remove single quote in column name

```
Select Sum("Unit Price") as TotalPrice, 
Count("Order ID") as NumOfDiffProds, 
Avg(Quantity) as AchQuantity, Avg(Discount) as AvgDiscount
FROM TableName;
```

Comment: That didn't appear to do anything

Comment: @Domtheanon you didn't put table name in your query and single qoute does not means column name it refer string value

Comment: I've updated my OP with the exact error as a comment as well. Please take another look.

Comment: @Domtheanon what is your dbms

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using **MySQL**. You can use *backticks* to reference table or column names with spaces:

```
Select 
    Sum(`Unit Price`) as TotalPrice, 
    Count(`Order ID`) as NumOfDiffProds, 
    Avg(`Quantity`) as AvgQuantity, 
    Avg(`Discount`) as AvgDiscount
From 
    `Order Details`
Where 
    `Order ID` = 1
```

An advice: try to avoid creating database objects with spaces in their names.